# Source of RegEx examples of Secret Detection patterns in repositories?

Tags: git, secrets-management, regex

Where can I find RegEx that can pattern match common secret strings?

I have a product that scans repos and commits and in case a developer tries to commit a secret (i.e. passwords, keys). It scans for roughly 30 patterns by default which seems insufficient given thousands of repos in over seventy languages. I can expand that scanning with RegEx. However, I don't know every common secret there is.

Is there a framework, list, or tool that can provide RegEx or patterns for likely secrets?

Where can I get comprehensive lists of secret types?

Or am I doomed to writing a metric ton of RegEx then being held responsible for when something is missed?

Comment: "Find all the secrets!!" is not a specification. You are tying the impact of missing a secret to the specification of the secrets you need to find. Until you can define what you are looking for, then you are looking for everything. So, this looks like an XY Problem. What's the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Agreed. I was just hoping that there was an existing corpus of well researched secret text patterns. Or maybe a framework has already defined what I ought to be looking for as a best practice?

Comment: How does one create a regex for what should be random strings?

Comment: Metadata, headers, length. A variety of AppSec or Secret Discovery products match patterns in this way. Check out some examples: https://github.com/dxa4481/truffleHogRegexes/blob/master/truffleHogRegexes/regexes.json

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I linked to a an example with roughly 40 RegEx examples like I hope to use. These 6 contributors sourced the patterns from 3 researcher's work in 1 paper. My ideal answer might point to something a bit more broadly planned. Are any AppSec vendors discovering secret patterns "in the wild" and then publishing their research?

Comment: Right, but they have defined what they are looking for. You are, by your statement, looking for "every common secret there is". If you know your infrastructure and product, then you should be able to refine your search to the secrets that are likely to be in code/configs your devs might commit.

Comment: You're absolutely more correct that I should have definite requirements.  However, I'm in a 200,000+ employee, multi-cloud, global data centers organization. No one person will every understand the infrastructure. So my ask is if there is anything "common" and/or "comprehensive"? Any CIS repository standard? Any vendor that's mapped all cryptographic key algorithms? Anyone who's amassed a list by consolidating RegEx strings from multiple secret management products? Anything more substantial than lists backed by one company or one paper?

Comment: @QuantenGhost **(a)** "_Are any AppSec vendors discovering secret patterns "in the wild" and then publishing their research_" if they are _AppSec vendors_, they probably won't be publishing the IP they discover, otherwise they'll be less able to continue selling their expertise. **(b)** "_then being held responsible for when something is missed?_" You will never be able to reliably discover _every_ instance of a secret: all you can aim to do is catch as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are some existing published regular expression patterns which try to detect some categories of secrets. These usually rely on the standardized structure of private keys and tokens provided by concrete implementations.

See for example [gitleaks](https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks/blob/1b3f10cb79e2d87bb5098f9b6a10b3c36eb48f6e/config/gitleaks.toml).

Some patterns which are already available:

- For matching AWS secret keys: `(?i)aws(.{0,20})?(?-i)['\"][0-9a-zA-Z\/+]{40}['\"]`
- For matching a few types of asymmetric private keys: `-----BEGIN ((EC|PGP|DSA|RSA|OPENSSH) )?PRIVATE KEY( BLOCK)?-----`

Of course, there is no guarantee that *all* secrets will be found. It may be worth considering an alternative solution: education. By making developers more aware of the dangers of publishing secrets to repositories, they are less likely to commit such mistakes.